# Out schema for dissolving shapes

Tags: dissolve, shapely, fiona

I have a code which goes like this

```
with fiona.open(some_file, 'r') as to_dissolve:
    out = to_dissolve.schema
    with fiona.open(another_file, 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', out) as dissolved:
        # Get properties
        dissolved.write({'geometry': geom, 'properties': property})
```

The problem is that when multiple points are dissolved, they become multi-points instead. How do I make sure that the output schema will always match no matter what sort of inputs I get?

Comment: You Need to coerce all the geoms to be MultiPoints - even if they're MultiPoints of one. If you post the code that does the dissolving it will be easier to make more concrete suggestions.

Comment: My issue is that I'm not necessarily dissolving points. I may be dissolving lines, polygons, etc.